# while using blobstore service of GAE, how to use ajax call to upload an image instead of form fields?

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, blobstore, image-upload

While using blobstore service of GAE, how to use AJAX call to upload an image instead of form fields?

Since I want the control back to the page without reloading the page, where the upload file input is, I don't want to use the form field, I am using the AJAX call.

GAE docs have crystal clear examples on how to do that, but with form fields.

Comment: You don't have to reload the page when you use an upload form.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define a submit handler for form (http://api.jquery.com/submit/) and your page won't be reloaded. Instead, control will go to the handler you defined where you can fetch the image and display it. That's how I do it (using GWT however).